# Parse.com - How to obtain ParseUser from ParseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve 2 values from my Cloud Code function. A List of ParseUser and a List of ParseObject.

This is a snippet of the Cloud Code.

```
...
var finalResult = {"users":users,"groups":groups};
//users is an array of Parse.User 
//groups is an array of Parse.Object
response.success(finalResult);
```

This is the call from the client.

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("serviceUpdate", new HashMap<String, Object>(),new FunctionCallback<HashMap<String, List<ParseObject>>>() {
     public void done(HashMap<String, List<ParseObject>> result, ParseException e) {
       if (e == null) {
         List<ParseObject> users = result.get("users");
         List<ParseObject> groups = result.get("groups");
```

As you can see, `users` is now a ParseObject. How can I obtain the ParseUser? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use casting, as follows:

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("serviceUpdate", new HashMap<String, Object>(),new FunctionCallback<HashMap<String, List<ParseObject>>>() {
     public void done(HashMap<String, List<Object>> result, ParseException e) {
       if (e == null) {
         List<ParseUser> users = result.get("users");
         List<ParseObject> groups = result.get("groups");
```

Comment: I've tried casting but it doesn't work. I ended up using the `ParseObject`  instead since I don't really need the methods of `ParseUser`. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain as results Parse User you have to query the "User" table with this specific query https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#users-querying.
So you can retrieve the unique id from your posted query (it is a string) and then use that as filter for the new query.